# making photo collage using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How is it possible to make a photo collage using `tikz` with some photos with for instance put one with some angle on the top and the rest would be showing with some parts hidden under the first picture?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}};
\node at (2,2) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}};
\node[rotate=30] at (1,2) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, is it possible to keep original pixel without scale? I wish to keep original image quality!

Comment: @lucky1928 `\includegraphics[]{example-image}` will include it with the original size